# Change some object's parameter in a different objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I had such array of objects

```
[ { id: 2,
    name: 'woda',
    price: 45.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    shopId: 2 },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'sham',
    price: 69.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    shopId: 2 } ]
```

All I want to do it's multiple quantity parameter by newArray = [3,4] to get such result

```
[ { id: 2,
    name: 'woda',
    price: 45.98,
    quantity: 3,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    shopId: 2 },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'sham',
    price: 69.98,
    quantity: 4,
    createdAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    updatedAt: 2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z,
    shopId: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Please look into `Array.map` for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update every index of your array by the number at the same index of the array, a simple for loop works great. But you're gonna have a problem if `mult` is shorter than array

```js
var arr = [ { id: 2,
    name: 'woda',
    price: 45.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
    shopId: 2 },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'sham',
    price: 69.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
    shopId: 2 } ];

var mult = [3,4];

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]['quantity'] = mult[i] * arr[i]['quantity'];
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[ { id: 2,
    name: 'woda',
    price: 45.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: "2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z",
    shopId: 2 },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'sham',
    price: 69.98,
    quantity: 1,
    createdAt: "2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z",
    shopId: 2 } ]
    
    function sometingCool(arr,multipleByThisArr){
 var i=0;
 return arr.map(x=>{
  x.quantity=x.quantity*multipleByThisArr[i];
  i++;
  return x; 
 })

}
console.log(sometingCool(arr,[3,4]))
```

Comment: Don't use `map` if you want to iterate over an object. Use `forEach`.

Comment: @Cerbrus i wont.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to do this. The first choice is to use `map` operator:

```
let fooArray = [ { id: 2,
        name: 'woda',
        price: 45.98,
        quantity: 1,
        createdAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
        updatedAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
        shopId: 2 },
      { id: 3,
        name: 'sham',
        price: 69.98,
        quantity: 1,
        createdAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
        updatedAt: '2019-07-23T17:50:43.033Z',
        shopId: 2 } ];
let newArray = [3,4];
```

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [...rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator (this way can be useful when you want to take a nested object):

```
fooArray = fooArray.map(({
    quantity,
    ...rest
}, i) => ({ ...rest, quantity : quantity * newArray[i]}));
console.log(fooArray);
```

or more simpler and readable `map()` function  without `...rest` operator and destructing assignment:

```
fooArray = fooArray.map((f,i) => {
    f.quantity = f.quantity * newArray[i]
    return f;
});
console.log(fooArray);
```

and the second way is to use `foreach` method. As Cerbrus adviced because it is semantically better, shorter code, easier to understand when you want to edit just one value:

```
fooArray.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.quantity = e.quantity * newArray[i];
})
console.log(fooArray);
```

What to use is up to you. We've just shows the ways that you can achieve that you want.

Comment: Don't use `.map` to iterate over an array if you are just updating one value...

Comment: @Cerbrus please, see my updated answer. However, why you don't like this idea?

Comment: `.forEach` is semantically better, shorter code, easier to understand... `.map` is meant to ___map___ an array of objects to an array of something else.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's subjective. I think it is perfectly fine to use `.map` in this example, because it *transforms* something, while `.forEach` indicates (for me) that something is done for each element, but not necessarily a transformation. "shorter code" and "easier to understand" are only applicable to this specific answer and also only because the author used a very complicated syntax for it. The only thing that would change when using map here, would be that you need to return `e`.

Comment: @Robert I am glad that it helped to you!:) You can upvote or mark it as an answer if you feel that it helped to you!:) [what should I do when someone answers to you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)